# Flutter RTL AppBar Icon postion

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, appbar

what I am asking for is to add an icon in appBar in flutter ... I have active the localization property so my App is RTL Now

```
  localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale("ar", "AR"), // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales
    ],
    locale: Locale("ar", "AR"), // OR Locale('ar', 'AE') OR Other RTL locales
```

... the problem is the drawer menu Icon in right which is right ... but when I add Icon in leading property in appBar it doesn't go to the left side ... but it replaced the drawer Icon !!!

// AppBar

```
  appBar: new AppBar(

    leading: Icon(Icons.person,),

    title: new Text("الرئيسية",
      style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RPT Bold',
      fontSize: 16.0,
        color: Colors.amber
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.amber),
  ),
```

Best regards

Comment: This is probably worth [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `automaticallyImplyLeading`  to false :

```
appBar: new AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    leading: Icon(Icons.person,),
    title: new Text("الرئيسية",
   style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RPT Bold',
   fontSize: 16.0,
     color: Colors.amber
   ),
 ),
 centerTitle: true,
 iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.amber),
),
```

Comment: Thank you but .. Nothing changed!!

Comment: try to put your icon in the actions property maybe that's what you are looking for

Comment: Yes ... that's work ... when I add it inside action it appears correctly

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap your Scaffold with `Directionality` and set text direction to `RTL`.
this way doesn't need localization property.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('title'),
          ),
          body: Container(child: Text('text',
        ),
       ),
      ),
    );
  }
```